# Вызов командной строки в папке

Tags: c#, cmd

Имеется следующий код:

```
string command = string.Empty;
DirectoryInfo dInfoForTesting = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\TestFiles");
FileInfo[] files = dInfoForTesting.GetFiles();
Random rnd = new Random();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"E:\TestFiles",
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = false
};

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string rndPswd = "134";
    command = "arj a -m1 -g" + rndPswd + " " + file.Name + ".arj " + file.Name;
    startInfo.Arguments = command;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Собственно, задача состоит в том, чтобы вызывать архиватор ARJ в нужной папке через командную строку, передавать ему соответствующую команду (`command`) и создавать таким образом защищённый паролем архив (путь к данному архиватору уже прописан в переменной `PATH`, так что можно спокойной обращаться к нему через команду `arj`). Сама команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
arj a -m1 -g134 10.arj 10
```

где
a - это создание архива
-m1 - режим архивации
-g134 - защитить архив паролем 134
10.arj - название архива
10 - файл, который будет заархивирован

Проблема состоит в том, что если просто в папке `E:\TestFiles` вызвать командную строку и в ней написать данную команду для того же файла с именем 10, то создастся архив. Но если запустить мой код, то ничего не произойдёт. Помогите разобраться, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг кому поможет

Необходимо добавить в строку `command` либо `/c`, либо `/k`, где

```
/c - cmd выполняет команду и завершает работу
/k - то же самое, но продолжает работу
```

`command = "/c arj a -m1 -g" + rndPswd + " " + file.Name + ".arj " + file.Name;`

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно вызывать командную строку, вам нужно вызвать в этой папке сам arj.exe:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"E:\TestFiles",
    FileName = "arj.exe", // или просто arj
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = false
};

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string rndPswd = "134";
    command = "a -m1 -g" + rndPswd + " " + file.Name + ".arj " + file.Name;
    startInfo.Arguments = command;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```